# Passing Objects through Heap Sort

Tags: object, heapsort

Having issues trying to pass an object class to be sorted via Heap Sort. Basically I have a class which holds employee data such as names, address, phone numbers and employee ID. We are to use Heap Sort to pass this class as a object and sort it by employee ID. My main issue is converting my heap sort structures to where they can take objects. This is for a beginning data structures course so we're not allowed to use advanced techniques. My road block is I'm stumped as to how to pass my objects into the heap sort methods which currently only take primitive data types.

Office Class:

```
public class Office_Staff
{
    public String Name , Dept , Phonenumber;
    public int Id, years;

Office_Staff()
{
  Id = ("");
  Name = (""); 
  Dept = (""); 
  Phonenumber = ("");
  years = 0;
}
Office_Staff(int empid ,String empname, String empdept , String empphone, int service)
{
  Id = empid;
  Name = empname;
  Dept = empdept;
  Phonenumber = empphone;
  years = service;
}
public void setId(int empid)
{
  Id = empid;
}           
public void setName(String empname)
{
  Name = empname;
}
public void setDept(String empdept)
{
  Dept = empdept;
} 
public void setPhone(String empphone)
{
  Phonenumber = empphone;
}
public void setYears(int service)
{
  years = service;
}
public String getId()
{
  return Id;
}
public String getName()
{
  return Name;
}
public String getDept()
{
  return Dept;
}
public String getPhone()
{
  return Phonenumber;
}
public int getYears()
{
  return years;
}

public String toString()
{
  String str = "Office_Staff Name : " + Name + "Office_Staff ID : " + Id +
                 "Office_Staff Deaprtment : " + Dept + "Office_Staff Phone Number : " 
                 + Phonenumber + "Years Active : " + years;
  return str;
}

}
```

Heap Sort:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.*;


class zNode

{

   private int iData;             


public zNode(int key)           

{ 

  iData = key; 

}

public int getKey()

{ 

  return iData; 

}

public void setKey(int k)

{

  iData = k; 

}

} 



class HeapSort

{

   private int [] currArray;

   private int maxSize;          

   private int currentSize;

   private int currIndex;


HeapSort(int mx)            

{

  maxSize = mx;

  currentSize = 0;

  currArray = new int[maxSize];  

}


//buildheap

public boolean buildHeap(int [] currArray)

{

  int key = currIndex;

  if(currentSize==maxSize)

     return false;

  int newNode = key;

  currArray[currentSize] = newNode;

  siftUp(currArray , currentSize++);

  return true;

}


//siftup

public void siftUp(int [] currArray , int currIndex)

{

  int parent = (currIndex-1) / 2;

  int bottom = currArray[currIndex];


  while( currIndex > 0 && currArray[parent] < bottom )

  {

     currArray[currIndex] = currArray[parent];  

     currIndex = parent;

     parent = (parent-1) / 2;

  }  

  currArray[currIndex] = bottom;

 }


//siftdown

public void siftDown(int [] currArray , int currIndex)

{

  int largerChild;

  int top = currArray[currIndex];       

  while(currIndex < currentSize/2)       

  {                               

     int leftChild = 2*currIndex+1;

     int rightChild = leftChild+1;


     if(rightChild < currentSize && currArray[leftChild] < currArray[rightChild] )

        largerChild = rightChild;

     else

        largerChild = leftChild;


     if( top >= currArray[largerChild] )

        break;


     currArray[currIndex] = currArray[largerChild];

     currIndex = largerChild;            

   }  

   currArray[currIndex] = top;            

   }


//remove max element

public int removeMaxElement(int [] currArray)          

{                           

  int root = currArray[0];

  currArray[0] = currArray[--currentSize];

  siftDown(currArray , 0);

  return root;

}  


//heapsort

private void _sortHeapArray(int [] currArray)

{

  while(currentSize != 0)

  {

     removeMaxElement(currArray);

  }

}


public void sortHeapArray()

{

  _sortHeapArray(currArray);

} 


//hepify

private int[] heapify(int[] currArray) 

{

  int start = (currentSize) / 2;

  while (start >= 0) 

  {

     siftDown(currArray, start);

     start--;

  }

  return currArray;

}


//swap

private int[] swap(int[] currArray, int index1, int index2) 

{

  int swap = currArray[index1];

  currArray[index1] = currArray[index2];

  currArray[index2] = swap;

  return currArray;

}


//heapsort

public int[] _heapSort(int[] currArray) 

{

  heapify(currArray);

  int end = currentSize-1;

  while (end > 0) 

  {

     currArray = swap(currArray,0, end);

     end--;

     siftDown(currArray, end);

  }

  return currArray;

}

public void heapSort()

{  

  _heapSort(currArray);


}
```

Comment: If you can't modify the HeapSort routine, one solution is to have OfficeStaff (please don't use underscores in Java IDs like that, people will stare...) subclass ZNode (please don't start java class names with a lower case letter.  nitpick much? no really, tho - it's a thing)  and override the (get/set)Key methods.   Really though, that's "dirty", the HeapSort should be a generic-typed method.   Not sure if thats "advanced"....

Comment: we're allowed to modify the given Heap Sort routine, but instead of it taking the integers (example: buildHeap(int [] currArray)) it needs to take it as a object: buildHeap(OfficeStaff [] currArray). Its when I get down into the code below I start getting "cant convert from int to object etc..." errors. And thank you for the notes on the syntax. As for overriding the methods i'm not really sure how to do that.

Comment: You should post what you have for your heapsort using the OfficeStaff so far. It seems like you want to use currArray[I].getId() to compare in your siftDown method. You will also need to convert the Id to an integer.

Comment: not too familiar with how to use compare. I also changed ID to interger to make it easier so I can sort the list of names by ID.